# Getting random rows based on column index

Tags: sql, postgresql

As of right now the table setup is like so:

```
CREATE TABLE testing (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    text TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
) UNIQUE KEY (id);
```

This essentially stores quotes from people, and what I would like to do is have a random quote on each query. As of right now, I am able to minimize it down to selecting a single user and a quote via:

```
SELECT name, MIN(text)
FROM testing
INNER JOIN users
ON users.id = testing.id
GROUP BY name
```

However, this will not select a random text each time if there are multiple. How can I support getting a different one each time without duplicate rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `row_number()` and `random()` functions:

```
select name, text
from (SELECT name, text, row_number() over (partition by name order by random()) as seqnum
      FROM testing t INNER JOIN
           users u
           ON u.id = t.id
      ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to produce duplicate rows (as far as names are concerned)